# Can I limit the amount of claims received in my SP?

Tags: cookies, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I have an MVC-application that uses an external Idp to authenticate users with SAML. My app is using sustainsys-SAML2.
The Idp has different ways to log in and on one of them the Saml-resonse is very large and it will create a large number of fedAuth-cookies that will make the header too big and i will get a 400 - headear too large. 
Since I do not have any control over the Idp and it is used in other applications I wonder if there is a way for me, in my application, to limit what claims/attributes i want to receive since I do not need all the extra information for my app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to limit it using your SAML metadata:

```
<md:AttributeConsumingService index="1">
   <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en-US">your service name</md:ServiceName>
   <md:ServiceDescription xml:lang="en-US">your service description</md:ServiceDescription>
   <md:RequestedAttribute Name="string">
      <saml:AttributeValue>any content</saml:AttributeValue>
   </md:RequestedAttribute>
</md:AttributeConsumingService>
```